# Advice with if statements and using input

Tags: python

I'm working on a school exercise on python and its asking me to give a customer a 20% discount if their purchase is between $10 and $20. Then a 30% discount for purchases between $21 and $30. Every time I enter a number between 21 and 30 it gives me a 20% and 30% discount, how do i make it give me JUST a 30% discount. Also pyscrpiter says unorderable types in line 2. How do I resolve this error

```
    productprice=input ('Enter price of product')
if productprice > 10:
        discount = productprice*0.80
if productprice> 20:
        discount = productprice*0.70
```

Comment: Is this Python 3.x, or 2.x? In 3.x, `input` returns a string, and you can't compare a string and a number like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Python3.x version**

```
productprice = float(input('Enter price of product'))
if 10.0 <= productprice <= 20.0:
    afterDiscount = productprice * 0.80
elif 20.1 <= productprice <= 30.0:
    afterDiscount = productprice * 0.70
else:
    afterDiscount = productprice
print (afterDiscount)
```

**Python2.x version**

```
productprice = float(raw_input('Enter price of product'))
```

**Notes**

1. In Python, you can check whether a number is in given range, like this.

   ```
   0 < num < 3
   ```

   If it is valid mathematically, then it will return `True`, `False` otherwise.
2. It is always good to have the `else` part.

Comment: In Python 2.x, you don't want `float(input(…))`. Ideally use `float(raw_input(…))`… but if you insist on using `input`, the whole point is to let it do the parsing for you, so you don't need to convert after the fact. On the other hand, in Python 3.x, `print` isn't a statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
productprice = float(raw_input('Enter price of product '))

if  30 >= productprice >= 21:
        productprice *= 0.70
elif  20 >= productprice >= 10:
        productprice *= 0.80

print(productprice)
```

Your input must be converted to an int or float in order to compare it to numbers. Also, using elif ensures you only give one discount

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using an "else".  First if you check if it falls in the lower price range, and if it does it executes the first if and ignores the else.  You also need to make compound statements (`productprice >= 10 and productprice <= 20`).  I don't know how python works with reading input, but you might need to convert from a String to an integer to fix the line 2 error.

Answer (score 1):

```
productprice=int(input ('Enter price of product'))
if productprice > 20 and productprice < 31:
    discount = productprice*0.70
elif productprice> 10:
    discount = productprice*0.80
```

Comment: Python doesn't use `&&`.